# Enforcing file upload size on GAE

Tags: apache, google-app-engine, upload

I am trying to figure out how to enforce the maximum size of a file being uploaded to my app engine application. I have the following code, but it doesn't seem to work, as I was able to upload a 10mb file. Any ideas?

```
ServletFileUpload upload = new ServletFileUpload();
upload.setFileSizeMax(5242880);
FileItemIterator iter = null;
try {
    iter = upload.getItemIterator(request);
} catch (FileUploadException e) {
    System.out.println(1);
    e.printStackTrace();
}
// Parse the request
try {
    while (iter.hasNext()) {
        FileItemStream item = iter.next();
        String name = item.getFieldName();
        InputStream stream = item.openStream();
        if (item.isFormField()) {
            System.out.println("Form field " + name + " with value "
                + Streams.asString(stream) + " detected.");
        } else {
            System.out.println("File field " + name + " with file name "
                + item.getName() + " detected.");
            // Process the input stream
            System.out.println("ct: "+item.getContentType());
        }
     }
} catch (FileUploadException e) {
    System.out.println(2);
    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```